# setting value in $.post not work

Tags: jquery

i'm using ajax for update in database and using below code, problem is i cant set newValue in $.post method. this value defined.

```
$('#sabt_mored1').live('click', function() {
    $edit=false;
    var newVal=false;
    $(this).parent().siblings('td').find('#cd_e0').hide();              

    $.post("actions.php", {id_sal: id_sal, sal:sal1 , postaction:'virayeshe_sal'}, 
        function(data){
            if(data.success) {
                newVal=true;
            }
            else{
                newVal=false;                       
            }
        },'json');

    alert(newVal);              
    return false;               
});
```

after use alert i get false but i must be get , $.post returned data.success

Comment: perform the `alert(newVal)` inside of your success function. its being called before the $.post finishes.

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax call is asynchronous. The code in the callback function is not called until the result is returned from the server. The alert statement is executed immediately after initiating the request. At this time newVal will always have its default value of false.

You need to perform the actions that must happen after you have the result inside the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `alert()` is occurring *before* your ajax success callback function executes. Put the alert at the end of the callback and it will display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since `post()` is executing asynchronously, your `alert` statement needs to be inside the callback function to ensure that it is executed only after the AJAX operation is done:

```
$('#sabt_mored1').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $edit = false;
    var newVal = false;

    $(this).parent().siblings('td').find('#cd_e0').hide();              

    $.post("actions.php", {id_sal: id_sal, sal:sal1 , postaction:'virayeshe_sal'}, 
        function(data){
            if(data.success) {
                newVal=true;
            }
            else{
                newVal=false;                       
            }

            alert(newVal);
        },'json');           
});
```